# Redis Exception and Connection Refused Error Occurred

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, horizon

I have a Laravel project that is running by docker-compose. There's a `docker-compose.yml` to run the `redis` and `php` services. Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appetit-php:
    build:
     context: ./docker-file/php
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: appetit-php
   restart: always
   volumes:
     - ./services/legacy:/var/www/
     - ./docker-data/config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
     - ./docker-data/config/php/supervisor/conf.d/:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/
   working_dir: /var/www
   networks:
     - appetit-network

 appetit-redis:
  image: "redis"
  container_name: appetit-redis
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./docker-data/data/redis/:/data/
  ports:
    - "6378:6379"
  networks:
    - appetit-network
  

networks:
  appetit-network:
    driver: bridge
```

There's a permission error that I don't know how to fix, when I ran `php artisan horizon` everything was fine, but I got an error when I ran: `sudo php artisan horizon`. The error is:

```
 RedisException 

 Connection refused
 at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:161
```

Also, when I execute `whoami` I get the `root` as a result.
How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your "REDIS_HOST" in ``.env`` file? try to change it to "appetit-redis" and check if it works.

Comment: It is ```appetit-redis```, I think It's not about my config because everything works fine without running the horizon command without sudo.

Comment: have you checked docker compose logs for "appetit-redis"?

Comment: @HanieAsemi Are you using the right port? I see you exposed the port `6378` this is the reachable port on your host machine. but in your docker-compose network, you need to pass the `6379` and the PHP app can't reach the other port.